# В чём разница между видами инициализаций с++?

Tags: c++, winapi, компилятор, инициализация

Есть код:

```
STARTUPINFO si{ sizeof(si) };
```

Он работает без ошибок, но если попробовать другие способы инициализации, то код будет выдавать ошибки:

```
STARTUPINFO si = sizeof(si);
```

Тут компилятор Visual Studio ругается: "C++ не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "unsigned int" в "_STARTUPINFOA" ".

```
STARTUPINFO si( sizeof(si));
```

Тут вообще пишет: "идентификатор "si" не определен".

Comment: Последнее объявляет прототип функции.

Comment: Фигурные скобки не позволяют автоматически кастовать тип при инициализации, круглые - позволяют это делать, а если делать через `=` то нужен `operator=` в качестве метода. Почему у вас проблемы с этим - это уде другой вопрос. Я не могу сказать точно, но, по-моему, то что вы делаете вообще из разряда неопределенного поведения. В любом случае не выглядит верным для инициализации переменной использовать рамер этой же переменной, которая прямо в этой строчке объявляется.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а каким образом оно объявляет прототип функции, если в параметрах прототипа функции, используются спецификаторы типов, а насколько я знаю sizeof не является таковым.

Comment: @Qwertiy если бы скобки были пустые - тогда да, а в этом случае нет

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Comment: @n1kzzz, да, я перепутал со случаем с пустыми скобками.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, нет, он правильно инициализирует: у многих winapi-структур первым полем идёт её размер - [у этой в том числе](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa). А про необходимость оператора = при инициализации я не уверен - вроде он только для присваивания нужен, а тут его нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy по поводу operator= - да, он нужен, это требование стандарта, он нужен даже если речь идет о инициализации.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, тогда почему это скомпилировалось? https://ideone.com/zbwzkn Могу задать отдельным вопросом, если хочешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy минуточку, но это совершенно непохоже на код из примера. Измените правую часть на пременную (или константу) другого типа

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а для чего нужна перегрузка operator=, если речь идет об инициализации? Вроде как неважно перегружен этот оператор или нет, всеравно при инициализации через "=" мы попадаем в конструктор класса.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, тоже компилируется: https://ideone.com/94HavH.

Comment: 'STARTUPINFO si = sizeof(si);' - это не инициализация структуры. Этот вариант сработал бы, если бы справа стояла структура. Если же хочется инициализировать структуру одним числом, то его надо брать в фигурные скобки: `STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};` -это инициализирует первое поле, остальные поля будут инициализированы нулями.

Comment: @n1kzzz да, вы правы. Упустил этот момент

Comment: @Qwertiy да, действительно, мои слова были не верны - перепутал с другой фичей

Comment: @Vladimir, точно нулями?

Comment: @Qwertiy, книга: Дейтел П., Дейтел. Х. "С для программистов с введением в С11", раздел 10.3 Инициализация структур (стр .321) издательство АМК, М.:2014 г.: "Если инициализирующих значений в списке меньше, чем полей в структуре, остальные поля автоматически инициализируются нулевыми значениями (или значением NULL, если поле является указателем)." Этого достаточно или нужно искать в стандарте? И да, я видел в вопросе тег С++, но WinAPI - это Си, а не С++. И если бы в С++ это было реализовано не так же, то подозреваю, из С++ нельзя было бы пользоваться механизмами WinAPI.